# Handlebars.js: Render large data without blocking UI – deferred or lazy loading using setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, settimeout, handlebars.js

I want to load a large amount of data into a HTML table using [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), but the web browsers tend to freeze. So I am looking for a way to prevent the user interface from blocking.

Modifying the `each` helper the way I did cannot work, because the helper returns before generating `ret` is completed:

**JavaScript**:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('lazyeach', function(context, options) {
    var fn = options.fn;
    var i = 0, ret = "", data;

    if (Handlebars.Utils.isFunction(context)) { context = context.call(this); }

    if (options.data) {
        data = Handlebars.createFrame(options.data);
    }

    if(context && typeof context === 'object') {
        if (Handlebars.Utils.isArray(context)) {

            var loop = function() {

                for(var j = context.length; i<j; i++) {
                    if (data) {
                        data.index = i;
                        data.first = (i === 0);
                        data.last  = (i === (context.length-1));
                    }
                    ret = ret + fn(context[i], { data: data });

                    if (i % 100 == 0) {
                        i++;
                        setTimeout(loop, 5);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            loop();
        }
    }
    return ret;
});
```

**Handlebars template**:

```
<table>
    <!-- … -->
    <tbody>
    {{#lazyeach data}}
        <tr>
            {{#data}}
                <td>{{data}}</td>
            {{/data}}
        </tr>
    {{/lazyeach}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Do you know another approach or can you help me getting the current approach to work?

*EDIT:*
I am not stick to Handlebars.js. So if you know an alternative that makes the above possible, go ahead.

Comment: For this to work, Handlebars.registerHelper would have to support a promise being returned which it does not seem to do. Perhaps you can break the data down into smaller chunks before it is processed?

Comment: @Remento I've just wrote an helper (based on `each`) that slices the context into chunks of 500 and changed the template to `{{#eachFromTo data 0 499}}<tr>…</tr>{{/eachFromTo}} {{#eachFromTo data 500 999}}<tr>…</tr>{{/eachFromTo}}` however it does not improve anything.

Comment: One probably would have to call Handlebars multiple times (and break the data before calling Handelbars) but I don't have a clue how this could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use what is already available through js and implement a hybrid solution?

```
<script>
var rowTemplateSource = $("#your-row-template").html();
var rowTemplate = Handlebars.compile(rowTemplateSource);

while(yourdata.length) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        rowTemplate(yourdata.splice(0,500)); //500 records per loop
    }, 500 /* 500ms between loops */);
}
</script>


<script id="your-row-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<table>
<!-- … -->
<tbody>
{{#each data}}
    <tr>
        {{#data}}
            <td>{{data}}</td>
        {{/data}}
    </tr>
{{/each}}
</tbody>
</table>
</script>
```

I've not tested this at all so there may be some tweaks that have to be made to the loop/etc for this to fit your needs, but I believe it should work.